# How do I deploy Web Site Projects in Visual Studio via Web Deploy?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure, webmatrix, webdeploy

I want to deploy a Web Site Project ([as opposed to a Web Application Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx)) from Visual Studio using web deploy so I can deploy to the Windows Azure Accelerator for Web Roles.

However, it appears there is no way to perform a web deploy for ASP.net Web Site Projects. **Does anyone know how to deploy Web Site Projects in Visual Studio via Web Deploy?**

Notes:

- I have done a successful deployment with a ASP.net Web Application Project (not ASP.net Website Project). Examples steps [here](http://waawebroles.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Creating%20and%20Deploying%20a%20Website%20using%20Web%20Deploy).
- WebMatrix allows deployment through WebDeploy for the ASP.net Web Pages, but I am having separate issues with it, and I would rather work and deploy from Visual Studio.
- I am using the [ASP.net Web Pages](http://www.asp.net/web-pages) framework. (You can start a Web Pages project in Visual Studio by clicking File > New Web Site > "ASP.NET Web Site (Razor)"

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can get that with [Web Deployment Projects](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24509) for VS2010.  VS currently does not natively support Web Site Project deployment via WebDeploy.